# Exiting a method with switch case in a class to the method that called it in another class

Tags: java, switch-statement

I have a class with a method that calls a method located in another class, and that method has switch cases. Th e problem is that I am  not able to exit from the method with switch cases and get back to the next line after the method that called it. I have searched StackOverFlow for similar questions. I also tried to use the suggested solutions in those answers to questions related to exit from a switch case (using a conditional, using return, etc). Unfortunately, when I use these solutions, I don't go back to the next line in the method that called the switch case method. Rather, I am exiting the whole program with "Build Succeeded message".

Rather than being too abstract, I hope I am not flamed for posting some classes simulating the real problem I am facing. Sorry if the code is too long.

```
public class TestClass {
    ClassWithriginalMethod test;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ClassWithriginalMethod g = new ClassWithriginalMethod();
        g.presentMenuOptions();
    }

}
```

This class contains the main method.

The next class is the one which have a method that calls the method with switch cases:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;


public class ClassWithriginalMethod {
    private final ArrayList<ClassWithSwitchCases> arr;
    Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);

    public void presentMenuOptions() {
        System.out.println(
        "_____________________________________________________________________________\n"
        + "This Menu contains the following options:\n"
        + "Please choose a number corresponding to your option\n"
        + "1: to get create submenu\n"
        + "2: to get edit sub menu\n"
        + "3: to get view sub menu\n"
        + "4: to get delete sub\n" 
        + "5: to exit this operation\n"
        + "_____________________________________________________________________________\n");
        String str= s.nextLine();    
            switch (str) {
                case "1":
                    System.out.println("Entering creation...");
                    this.createMenu();//This method is working properly and user is moved to nextline, i.e shown the presentMenuOptions().
                    break;
                case "2":
                    System.out.println("Entering editing...");
                    /* The below method is the damn method that calls the other class methods with swith cases.*/
                    this.editMenu();
                    /*
                    ** What I want is to reach the next methos below this comment when I get back from the switch case. 
                    */
                    System.out.println("We've exited from the othe class method with switch cases...");
                    this.presentMenuOptions();
                    break;
                case "3":
                    System.out.println("Entering viewing...");
                    this.viewMenu();
                    this.presentMenuOptions();
                    break;
                case "4":
                    System.out.println("Entering deletion...");
                    this.deleteMenu();
                    this.presentMenuOptions();
                    break;
                default:
                    System.exit(0);
            }
    }

    public ClassWithriginalMethod() {
        this.arr = new ArrayList<>(0);
    }

    private void createMenu() {
        ClassWithSwitchCases toBeCreated = new ClassWithSwitchCases();
        this.arr.add(toBeCreated);
        this.checkingArraySize();

        this.presentMenuOptions();
    }

    private void editMenu() {
        this.checkingArraySize();
        System.out.println("The following objects are available. Please select the object with the corresponding index\n");
        this.arr.forEach(p -> System.out.printf("%-15d\t%-15s\t%-15s\n", arr.indexOf(p), p.getfName(),p.getsName())); // we print the array to see the indices and object main elems.
        int i = s.nextInt();
        ClassWithSwitchCases toBeEdited = this.arr.get(i); //supposedly I am checking through another function if the object of index i is in the array.
        toBeEdited.edit(toBeEdited); // it is here where we are calling the switch method in the other class
        //this.presentMenuOptions();
    }

    private void viewMenu() {
        this.checkingArraySize();
        System.out.println("The following objects are available. Please select the object with the corresponding index");
        this.arr.forEach(p -> System.out.printf("%-15d\t%-15s\t%-15s\n", arr.indexOf(p), p.getfName(),p.getsName())); // we print the array to see the indices and object main elems.
        int i = s.nextInt();
        ClassWithSwitchCases toBeViewed = this.arr.get(i); //supposedly I am checking through another function if the provided number id less than size of List.
        toBeViewed.view(toBeViewed); // making this class calling the function in the other class
        //this.presentMenuOptions();
    }

    private void deleteMenu() {
        this.checkingArraySize();
        System.out.println("The following objects are available. Please select the object with the corresponding index");
        int i = s.nextInt();
        ClassWithSwitchCases deleted = this.arr.get(i); //supposedly I am checking through another function if the provided number id less than size of List.
        deleted.view(deleted); // making this class calling the function in the other class
        //this.presentMenuOptions();
    }

    private void checkingArraySize () {
        if (this.arr.size() <= 0) {System.out.println("There are no objects in the aray");}  
        else {
            arr.stream().map((p) -> {
                System.out.println("The following objects are available.");
                return p;
            }).forEachOrdered((p) -> {
                System.out.printf("%-15s\t%-15s\t%-15s\n", "index", "fName", "sName");
                System.out.printf("_____________________________________________________________________________\n");
                System.out.printf("%-15d\t%-15s\t%-15s\n", arr.indexOf(p), p.getfName(),p.getsName());
            });
        }
    }
}
```

The last class is the one with switch cases:

```
public class ClassWithSwitchCases {

    private String fName;
    private String sName;

    Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);

    public ClassWithSwitchCases() {
        System.out.println("Please enter first name");
        this.fName = s.nextLine();

        System.out.println("Please enter sur name");
        this.sName = s.nextLine();
    }

    public String getfName() {
        return fName;
    }
    public void setfName(String fName) {
        System.out.println("Please enter first name");
        this.fName = fName;
    }
    public String getsName() {
        return sName;
    }
    public void setsName(String sName) {
        System.out.println("Please enter sur name");
        this.sName = sName;
    }
    public void edit(ClassWithSwitchCases o) {
        System.out.println(
        "_____________________________________________________________________________\n"
        + "The Edit Menu contains the following options:\n"
        + "Please choose a number corresponding to your option\n"
        + "1: to edit the object's first name\n"
        + "2: to edit the object's sur name\n"
        + "3: to exit this menu\n"
        + "_____________________________________________________________________________\n");

        do {
        switch (s.nextLine()) {

            case "1": 
                o.setfName(s.nextLine());
                System.out.println(o.toString());// just to check if editing took place
                this.edit(o); // put so that we can make other edits.
                break;
            case "2": 
                o.setsName(s.nextLine());
                System.out.println(o.toString());// just to check if editing took place
                this.edit(o); 
                break;
            case "3":
                System.out.println("We are leaving the method with switch cases...");
                break;
            default:
                System.out.println("We are also leaving the method with switch cases...");
                break;
        }
            } while ((Integer.getInteger(s.nextLine()) <= 3) && (Integer.getInteger(s.nextLine()) > 0));
    }
    public void view(ClassWithSwitchCases o) {
        System.out.println(o.toString());
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "_____________________________________________________________________________\n"
                + "First Name:" + this.getfName() + "\n" 
                + "Middle Name:" + this.getsName() + "\n" 
                + "_____________________________________________________________________________\n";

    }
}
```

If you try to work these classes, you will notice:

1. I am able to execute the `createMenu()` method, and then I get the presentMenuOptions() method, as supposed to be.
2. The `viewMenu()` and `deleteMenu()` methods do their work, but they exit from the whole program.
3. The `editMenu()` method is giving me nullPointerExeption, but I have no idea which pointer is that.
4. I have indicated in the comments in the code what I was thinking of.
5. I added extra `System.out.println()` messages, as a way to debug my code. Since I am only a beginner, this is as far as I can go at this stage.

If there is any general value from my question it is: How to exit from a method with switch cases and go back to another method, not necessarily the main method.

Many thanks for you help and patience :)

Comment: `return`, maybe?

Comment: @Joe C: In one of the answers where they are using a conditional, they instructed the person who asked to remove any return statements, and use break.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the return statement anywhere in the switch. Most likely, you want to change your break statements to return statements.

Comment: I just did, recompiled, I am able only to exit from the whole program. The message I am getting is:
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 42 seconds)

which is not what I want. I want to go back to my presentMenuOptions() method.

When I do want to exit the whole program I can use System.exit(0), for example.

Comment: Did it enter any of the switch clauses - or did it go to the default - which is system.exit()?

Comment: @ Just another Java programmer: In both cases when I was using break and when I changed to return, I was able to go to the method with switch cases. This is what persentMenuOptions does. The difference happens in getting back to this function from the method with with cases. With the break() way, when I entered a value that invalidates my condition it gave me the null pointer exception. When I used the return statement, I exited from the whole program. 
I deliberately made one of the cases in presentMenuOption to exit the whole app, hence the use of system.exit() there.

Comment: @another Java programmer: sorry. It executed the case: "3" where the exit should happen, and also moved to the default.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that while my question is valid, it is not the core problem. The core problem is how do I envision my classes (Objects) and how they are related to each other. In other words, I faced this problem because of the way I orchestrated my solution. If I chose another orchestration (i.e, more proper design patterns), most probably I was not going to face this issue.

It also seems to me that beginners (I am one of them) who are serious to build a big solution will face this "problem pattern" (asking either silly questions, or evading questions like "Why you are doing this? What were you aiming to achieve?" because they run quickly into implementing certain classes while they have not figured out the overall structural, behavioral, and creational aspects of the solution.

Interestingly, though, is that by making these mistakes, they learn.

Thanks for those who answered me and those who will answer or comment.